# Arc length of integral curve

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a following problem: Calculate arc length: $$y = \int_{-3}^x \frac {\sqrt {1-4t}} t\,dt$$    for $-3 \le t \le -1$.

I don't really understand why they are asking for the interval for t...

I'm using the formula for arc length which is integral of $\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ , and to get $y'$ I use first fundamental theorem of Calculus, so I get $y'$ same as integrand but with $x$ instead of $t$, but then, do I still consider the intervals from $-3$ to $-1$ or do I have to change it somehow? I got to the point: $$y = \int_{-3}^{-1} \frac {\sqrt {x^2 -4x +1}} {x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: Isn't $\;y\;$ a function of $\;x\;$ and not of $\;t\;$ ? Then its length should be evaluated according to $\;x\;$, not $\;t\;$ . I alos thing you should square the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given:

$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{1-4x}}x\implies\sqrt{1+y'^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1-4x}{x^2}}=\frac1{-x}\sqrt{x^2-4x+1}=-\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-3}}{x}$$

since $\;-3\le x\le -1\implies\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x\;$

So you have to solve

$$-\int_{-3}^{-1}\frac{{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-3}}}x\,dx$$

Comment: The outcome of this integral seems to be a very, very ugly number.

Answer (score 0):

Yea but the function is integral with t as dummy variable, then with FFToC y' is a function of x. Also I made a mistake in the last equation, it's (-x) in denominator$$y = \int_{-3}^{-1} (\frac {\sqrt {x^2 -4x +1}} {-x}) dx$$

Comment: Why $-x$ instead of $x$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because $\;x<0\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo: I know, I was asking the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry...yet I think that's the reason as I did the same. Excuse the question: and if you know, then why you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-4t}}t$ and $F(t)$ be some antiderivative of $f$. Then

$$y(x)=F(x)-F(-3).$$

Then the arc length between $-3$ and$-1$ is given by

$$L_{-3\to-1}=\int_{x=-3}^{-1}\sqrt{1+F'^2(x)}dx=\int_{x=-3}^{-1}\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}dx.$$

Note that defining $y$ from another starting point than $-3$ would make no difference as this only changes the integration constant, which vanishes by derivation.